# Bitmap from URI

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need a bitmap to work with and I am provided an URI that is shared from another apps implicit intent. I currently work with

```
           Bitmap btmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), urinormal);
```

but it takes up to half a second to create the bitmap. I need it to work as fast as possible, what can I do?

I can't find a way to reduce the quality of the bitmap, I can only apply BitmapFactory.options afterwards to create a smaller bitmap, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file size is too large. If it is large it takes the required time. You can do nothing about it.

If it takes around half seconds, you may want to perform the decoding using `AsyncTask` so that the UI won't freeze.

As you mentioned that you are developing a gallery type app. You may want to store the thumbnail of the bitmaps in the storage when loading them the first time. So next time your app can quickly decode the image from the thumbnail file. When you click on the image, you can load full size image from the original location.

As @faztp12 mentioned in his answer, you may also use some third party image loading libraries like Picasso or Glide to achieve the similar functionality.

Comment: I am trying to create something like a gallery app. It uses ViewPagers to go through the Images, so yeah I should probably do that.

Do you have any idea how Google Photos manages to do that Instantly and without reducing the resolution?

Comment: First time they load images, they save small image to different hidden files called thumbnails. You may want to implement that and load only thumbnail in the view. But when clicked in the thumbnail, open the full image. You may need to use a database for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why image loads slow. Slow connection, large file etc.
I would suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), an image loading library for android.

```
GlideApp
    .with(ctx)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

This will show a custom loading image until the image is loaded.
You will have to use [Generated API](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html) of Glide to have `GlideApp` class though. Read the docs, there are many other cool features.

Hope it helps.